# Is there any way to check if and/or how many are connected to IoT topic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I've read everything: aws-sdk documentation, IoT documentation, console documentation.

---

There really isn't much else to add:

Is there a way to check if and/or how many are subscriber to AWS IoT topic? Hacky ways?

---

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38964639/number-of-clients-connected-to-aws-iot-mqtt-topic) ask something vaguely similar but it's not the same & it doesn't have an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy way to query that information directly from AWS IoT. But since you asked for "hacky ways" there is a way to detect when any device subscribes and unsubscribes from a topic using the message data from  [AWS Reserved Topics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/topics.html#reserved-topics) - specifically these topics below:

```
$aws/events/subscriptions/subscribed/{clientId}
$aws/events/subscriptions/unsubscribed/{clientId}
```

You could create an IoT rule to forward all `subscribed` and `unsubscribed` events from those reserved topics to S3, DynamoDB or RDS to be queryable. A simple Lambda function to increment on subscribes and decrement on unsubscribes within DynamoDB would work really well too. ([DynamoDB Atomic Counter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html#API_UpdateItem_Example_Atomic_Counter))

Also here's what the message body looks like - from [Subscribe/Unsubscribe Events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/life-cycle-events.html#subscribe-unsubscribe-events):

```
{
    "clientId": "186b5",
    "timestamp": 1460065214626,
    "eventType": "subscribed" | "unsubscribed",
    "sessionIdentifier": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "principalIdentifier": "000000000000/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU:some-user/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU:some-user"
    "topics" : \["foo/bar","device/data","dog/cat"\]
}
```

Comment: I've figured it out eventually & I decided to go with my own EC2 WebSockets server(s). IoT feels very hacky for web stuff, every step feels like you're going against the grain.

Comment: There are some stuff that is a little rough around the edges. For us the biggest pro was the scaleability of the service.